# How to set the style in WPF Window.Resources.

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, window, styles

I want to create multiple styles in the Window.Resources. Below is the code I tried, but it's not working:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="StyleOne" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Control.Height" Value="20"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="StyleTwo" BasedOn="{StaticResource StyleOne}">
        <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Control.Height" Value="20"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Button Style="{StaticResource StyleOne}"></Button>
<Button Style="{StaticResource StyleTwo}"></Button>
```

It throws an error saying:

> The property "Content" is set more than once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with styles, the window can only contain one child (which sets the [`Content`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.content.aspx)), use some container which can contain more than one child. e.g. a [`StackPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.aspx) or [`Grid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx).

```
<StackPanel>
     <Button .../>
     <Button .../>
</StackPanel>
```

(See also: [Panels Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx))

Comment: i guess that wasnt the problem, because style element is only supported by window.resource and no other, i tried stackpanel and grid also, the problem was of the x:Type Control on my second style, which resolved by @Kishore Kumar, anyways thanks, for giving your time

Answer (score 5):

set the target type for the second style

```
 <Style x:Key="StyleTwo"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource StyleOne}"
           TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Setter Property="Control.Background"
                Value="Red"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Control.Height"
                Value="20"></Setter>
    </Style>
```

put the buttons inside a stackpanel or Grid

Answer (score -2):

I guess BasedOn inherits the properties from other style type and you have

```
    Property="Control.Background"
```

set in both the styles hence getting an error

```
    "The property "Content" is set more than once."
```